# How to keep original means/stddevs when using sklearn.preprocessing's StandardScaler?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm teaching myself regression using python, and have seen the following code in a guide. As will be obvious, it calls the ScandardScaler - fit_transform method - but also attempts to store the mean and std deviation (so that all can be standardized later)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

observations = len(dataset)
variables = dataset.columns
standardisation = StandardScaler(copy = False, with_mean = True, 
with_std = True)
Xst = standardization.fit_transform(X)
original_means = standardisation.mean_
original_stds = standardisation.std_
Xst = np.column_stack((Xst, np.ones(observations)))
y = dataset['Target'].values`
```

The error this generates is

> AttributeError: 'StandardScaler' object has no attribute 'mean_'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...so it turns out that starting from Scikit-Learn version 0.17, the attribute "mean_" and “std_”are no longer present as StandardScaler objects.

But

```
original_means = np.mean(X)
original_stds = np.std(X)
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the above code is fault.
The spelling mistake between two variables is the problem
Actual Standard Scaler that fit transformed is named standardization
`standardization.fit_transform(X)` but the mean called for is `standardisation.mean_`
See that **'z' vs 's'** difference